# Andengine, scaling an image to fill screen size, without mantaining aspect ratio

Tags: android, size, screen, andengine, aspect-ratio

I am trying to set an image with size of 960x640 pixels... My device has 854x480 pixels..

What I have done is to load the sprite, and then set as scene background...

```
sprite = new Sprite(0, 0, fieldITexture, BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().getVertexBufferObjectManager());
setBackground(new SpriteBackground(sprite));
```

But obviusly that image is getting outside of screen, i tried to use setScale and setScaleCenter, but i does not give any result... See this image: http://db.tt/pcuJa4vE

To set camera size, i have done it depending on the device:

```
final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
CAMERA_WIDTH = display.getWidth();
CAMERA_HEIGHT = display.getHeight();
mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
```

So, what can I do to scale the football field to the screen size? I dont care about aspect

Comment: why use display.getWidth()? you can use the build in scaling mechanisme

Comment: I think you can use other Sprite's constructors and specify the sprite width and height to your camera size instead of use the width/height of the texture region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use device.getWitdh() and device.getHeight() use fixed width and height

```
public final static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
public final static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
```

AndEngine will scale all the images for you, sometimes you will see a small black bar around the edges of the screen because of the scaling. but almost not noticable.

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions()
{
    camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), camera);
    return engineOptions;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i read that in andengine forums, but the thing is that I dont want to have those black bars...,what could I do????  Thanks

Comment: this is not the adviced way of working but you could achieve it with the following scenario: make use of the fixed height and witdh as above -> this will be your starting point. Calculate the difference in ratio between your starting point and device configurations (device.getWidth()). Scale your whole scene or every image within the scene with this ratio

Answer (score 4):

just to put it out there, I believe there are 2 major ratio's (5:3 and 4:3) for the devices.
Most others are closer to 5:3 than 4:3 (so 5:3 should be default).

I wanted to support the best graphics possible, without having to go through ALL screen sizes.
So i took those 2 ratios.

Now I made my setup like this:

define

```
String fileFolderForRatio = "";
    int CAMERA_WIDTH = 1280;
    int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 768;

@Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        instance = this;

        // getting the device's screen size
        Point screenSize = getScreenSizeByRatio();
        CAMERA_WIDTH = screenSize.x;
        CAMERA_HEIGHT = screenSize.y;


        mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR,
                new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
        engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
        engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true);

        return engineOptions;

    }
```

and the function (note the check for wide and height, sometimes AndEngine detects it the other way around)

```
public Point getScreenSizeByRatio()
    {
        final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        double sw = display.getWidth();
        double sh = display.getHeight();
        double ratio = sw / sh;
        if (sw < sh) ratio = sh/sw;

        Point screenPoints = new Point();
        if (ratio > 1.3 && ratio < 1.4)
        {

            fileFolderForRatio = "1024x768";
            screenPoints.x = 1024;
            screenPoints.y = 768;

        } else
        {

            fileFolderForRatio = "1280x768";
            screenPoints.x = 1280;
            screenPoints.y = 768;

        }

        Debug.e("RATIO", fileFolderForRatio);

        return screenPoints;
    }
```

Put the graphics (optimized for that screen size) in the 1024x768 folder and the 1280x768 folder.

This way you have semi-static screensize.
AndEngine will resize the rest for you.

(please not that for screen positioning of sprites you'll have to check as it's not the same for the 2 ratio's. 
But coming from a Ios developer it's not that difficult (iPad and iPhone)

Hope it helps

Comment: That actually works on my Galaxy Nexus, but I gotta say I didn't understand that well!

Comment: glad it helped. it more or less defines 2 standards and grabs the closest ratio for that standard. according to that ratio it selects files from the correct folder.

Answer (score -1):

Replace:
new RatioResolutionPolicy(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
with:
new FillResolutionPolicy ()

this fills up the whole screen.